# java transform value of char 2D array (letter) into integer (number)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, char

I'm confusing how to transform values in 2D char array into number (integer).

Let's assume the array is: `[[a, b],[c, d],[e, f]]` or `{{'a','b'},{'c','d'},{'e','f'}}`

All values in that array will be converted to number, a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, f=5.

I expect result like: `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]` or `{{0, 1},{2, 3},{4, 5}}`

If it's just a string of "abcdef", I can use charAt(), but I can' use it in an array, especially in char array. So, I use .replace.

```
package array_learning;

public class test {     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char [][] word= {{'a','b'},{'c','d'},{'e','f'}};  
        int strLength = word.length; 
        for(int i = 0; i<strLength; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
                String strWord = Character.toString(word[i][j]);
                strWord = strWord.replace("a","0");
                strWord = strWord.replace("b","1");
                strWord = strWord.replace("c","2");
                strWord = strWord.replace("d","3");
                strWord = strWord.replace("e","4");
                strWord = strWord.replace("f","5"); 
                System.out.print(strWord+" ");
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }     

    }
}
```

But, the result is not what I've expected.

Result:

```
0 1 

2 3 

4 5
```

How to solve this in the right way?

Comment: What do you mean with `[[a, b],[c, d],[e, f]]`? That's not valid Java syntax.

Comment: Your expected results and actual results posted appear to agree.  Is your problem just the format they are printed in?

Comment: There's no need to convert them to strings or use `replace`. Also, you say you are converting them to "number (integer)", but you are only changing them to a different chars that are digits. I hope you understand the difference.

Comment: @femtoRgon. Yes. The problem is how to transform letter to number without changing the value format. So, the result should be in 2D array too. How should I do that?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I think it is valid when we used Arrays.deepToString(). (Correct me if I'm wrong..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
import java.util.Arrays;   

public class Ctest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] word= { {'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}, {'e', 'f'} };

        println(word); // format with brackets e.g., [[a, b], [c, d]]
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(word)); // same format

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < word[i].length; j++) {
                if (word[i][j] >= 'a' && word[i][j] <= 'f') {
                    word[i][j] = (char) ((word[i][j] - 'a') + '0');
                }
            }
        }

        println(word); // formatted with brackets
        printPlain(word); // formatted without brackets
    }

    public static void println(char[][] word) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int j = 0; j < word[i].length; j++) {
                if (j > 0) System.out.print(", ");
                System.out.print(word[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("]");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    public static void printPlain(char[][] word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) System.out.print(", ");
            for (int j = 0; j < word[i].length; j++) {
                if (j > 0) System.out.print(", ");
                System.out.print(word[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The main changes I have made are that the values in the array are actually converted (I'm not sure if you want this; you weren't storing any new values back into the array before), the data is handled as `char` without being converted to `String`, the conversion is done with a calculation instead of a special case for each value, and converting the data and printing it have been separated from one another.

There are also a few minor changes. The data is now printed in the format you demonstrated, with brackets, there is no assumption that the inner arrays always have exactly two elements, and the class name has been changed to start with a capital letter.

One other minor note. On the line that converts the values from lower case letters to digits, the expression is in parentheses and is cast back to a `char`. This is because when you add and subtract `chars` Java performs a widening conversion to `int`, so to store the value back into the `char[][]` it is necessary to cast it to `char` again.

I had forgotten that there is already a method in Java in the `java.util.Arrays` class to format a multidimensional array with brackets: `Arrays.deepToString(word)` will give you the same format as the `println` method above. I had also shown a `printPlain` method which is similar, but lacks the brackets, if you prefer a cleaner output format. You could also easily modify this method so that it appends to a `StringBuilder` and returns a `String`, instead of printing the array directly.

Comment: Great, it works. But, is it possible to print as 2D array format without adding brackets [] or {}?

Comment: I'll add something about that. You can easily modify the `println` method above to leave out the brackets, or there is a built-in Java method (`Arrays.deepToString`) that will print it with the brackets.

Comment: On a side note, the convert from letter into number in the main method will only work on an letters a to j as the char '0' + 10 (10 is what k - a equals) is : and not 10 as noted in the follow up question from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734785/java-character-converting-into-number-in-2d-char-array

Comment: I hadn't seen the follow-up question, and restricted myself in this answer to just those letters that were in this question, but it's good to note that. To do what the follow-up question asks for requires a different approach. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is matching up correctly. This is a 2d array so your arrays are printing one by one.

If you don't want them to go on seperate lines then get rid of the `System.out.println();` statement at the end of the for loop.

Comment: The problem is how to put the transformation value into 2D array too. So, result should be {{"0","1"},{"2","3"},{"4","5"}}.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.toString()` to convert your array into string first. Then do the replacement. For example:

```
char [][] word= {{'a','b'},{'c','d'},{'e','f'}};  
String strWord = "";
for(char []w : word){
    // convert array int [x, y] format
    strWord += Arrays.toString(w)+",";
}
// removing comma(,) from end.
strWord = strWord.replaceAll(",$", "");

// do your replacement.
strWord = strWord.replace("a","0");
// ... more

// output
System.out.println("["+strWord+"]");
```

Comment: Ah, my eyes! It burns! The goggles do nothing!