# java character converting into number in 2D char array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert all letters in a 2D char array into number. As results, I want a = 0, b=1, c=2, ... z=25.

Then, I tried this as part of my code:

```
char [][] letters = {{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}};

for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
                if (letters[i][j] >= 'a' && letters[i][j] <= 'z') {
                   letters[i][j] = (char) ((letters[i][j] - 'a') + '0');
                } 
            }
        }
```

The result of my code is not what I expected before.

From 'a' to 'j', it worked well. But, from 'k' until 'z' it didn't print expected number.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: PLEASE show the declaration of letters and how it is populated.

Comment: Please explain why you're doing character arithmetic: `((letters[i][j] - 'a') + '0')`

Comment: Well your issue is that you are creating ascii number symbols from chars. The ascii table does not have 10 and higher numbers. So when you get number 10, the result probably is :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can't store the number 10 as a single char. It is two chars, 1 and 0. So the result array has to be something else than a char array. If it is `int` your working with then you are probably best of storing them in an int array.

`intarray[i][j] = (letters[i][j] - 'a');` where intarray is your array of int values that has the same size as the char array. Other option is to make a string array if you must store the result in the same array and convert it to a number and then into a string. Like this

```
String [][] letters = {{"i", "u"}, {"a", "g"}, {"e", "k"}};

for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
        if (letters[i][j].charAt(0) >= 'a' && letters[i][j].charAt(0) <= 'z') {
           letters[i][j] = Integer.toString((letters[i][j].charAt(0) - 'a');
        } 
    }
}
```

The reason is that the ascii table only has the numbers 0 to 9 as symbols. So in your case you get the first 10 letters to convert but after that you start getting various symbols in the ascii table. k for example would be :, l is ; m is < and so on. When you are working with converting chars to numbers you are better working with them as int as they are easier to do math on.

You could do the same without converting it into an int but that mean you need to find out char - 'a' is bigger than 10. If so you need get the number divided by 10 and then after that the modulo of the number and give each of them the associated ascii symbol to make them into a string. This is a lot more complex and hard to do, specially considering how easy this is by just doing it with ints.

There are 2 other options for you but I still feel the string option above is by far the easiest.

First would be to have the 2d array as an int. You could then initialize the ints to be letters. Then you can do arithmetic on them to find the number they fit. Like this:

```
int [][] letters = {{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}};

for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
        if (letters[i][j] >= 'a' && letters[i][j] <= 'z') {
            letters[i][j] = (letters[i][j] - 'a');
        } 
    }
}
```

This would have the same effect. The issue with doing it this way is that printing the actual letter takes a bit more effort and in the end you would need to convert it to a char. So I would not recommend this way.

The second option would be to store everything as the char value in a char array. Like this:

```
char [][] letters = {{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}};

for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
        if (letters[i][j] >= 'a' && letters[i][j] <= 'z') {
            letters[i][j] = (char) (letters[i][j] - 'a');
        } 
    }
}
```

To print this then you would need to cast the char to an int. So you could print them with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\n", (int) letters[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This would then work as well but it is a bit hacky and you need to make sure you cast the char you have to an int all the time. So far I think the string array is the best option but it depends on what your goal is. But one thing that you can't do is store the char '10' in a char array as '10' isn't a single char but 2 chars and don't fit in a char.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the OP's line, assuming it makes sense? `letters[i][j] = (char) ((letters[i][j] - 'a') + '0');` Character arithmetic is something I'm not familiar with. Is it intended as concatenation?

Comment: Well it does make sense for letters a to j (the first 10 letters). @aliteralmind The reason being that Char 'a' - 'a' + '0' gives us 97 - 97 + 48 in the ascii table. Ascii symbol 48 is 0. So the result would be the char '0'. However k is 107 so the formula is 107-97+48 which gives us 58 which is symbol 58 in the ascii table or :.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Not totally clear, but I get the idea.

Comment: @aliteralmind I can try to detail it a bit more as a the basic idea. Every char is basically an int. The int then represents a symbol in the ascii table (http://www.asciitable.com/). So if I create a char 'a' it can be looked at as the number 97. Just the same with the letter 'A' (capital A is a different symbol than a). 'A' is therefore 65. This means we can do math operations on chars which if we get read the result gives us another char in the ascii table. 'b' - 1  would then equal to 'a' in the table as a is 1 behind b in the table.

Comment: @Asthor, thanks for your explanation. I understand it now. Then, what should I do to fix my code? As you know the array is 2D char array, not string array. 

Btw, in your code, I think it's incompatible to convert string to int.

Comment: @Speaky Well you can't store a number bigger than 9 in a char spot, unless you store it as something else than a number. This is because 15 for example being to chars so it would require 2 spots in the char array. I would recommend either storing it in a different array than the char array you got (an int array) or if it has to be stored in the same array change the array type to either string like I did above or or in an int array (remember that chars are in basic ints) and then just handle them by printing them as a char. I'll update my answer later on to fit both.

Comment: @Speaky I've updated the answer for a string, char and int array now. All work with their own drawbacks. About the incompatibility of converting string, why wouldn't it be compatible? The code compiles and runs with the intended result.

Comment: @Asthor, it's an incredible explanation. It works very well. But, I have another problem. All characters are already converted to number (int). Previously, we have a char array 'char [][] letters = {{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}};' So, is it possible to return the converting values (number) into the char array? I mean, the previous array 'char [][] letters = {{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}};' will be 'char [][] letters = {{'8', '20'}, {'0', '6'}, {'4', '10'}};' ? If possible, how to apply it correctly?

Comment: @Speaky Just so I am sure on what you are asking. You wanna go from having a char array with values `{{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}}` and turning it into `{{'8', '20'}, {'0', '6'}, {'4', '10'}}`? No that is not possible. The reason being that '20' and '10' are not chars. The only numbers that are chars in the strict definition are 0-9 and when you combine 2 and 0 or 1 and 0 you get two chars, '2' and '0' or '1' and '0'. Therefore you can't do it like you are proposing.

Comment: @Speaky You can however if you want to initialize the array with numbers do `char [][] letters = {{8+'a', 20+'a'}, {0+'a', 6+'a'}, {4+'a', 10+'a'}};` and the chars will be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Asthor, I try to hack it by adding another int array. Like this: `char [][] lets = {{'i', 'u'}, {'a', 'g'}, {'e', 'k'}, {'v', 'b'}};
        int [][] numLets = new int[lets.length][lets.length]; //add this
        for (int i = 0; i < lets.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lets[i].length; j++) {
                if (lets[i][j] >= 'a' && lets[i][j] <= 'z') {
                    lets[i][j] = (char) (lets[i][j] - 'a');
                    numLets[i][j] = (int) lets[i][j]; //put it here
                } 
            }
        }`

Comment: @Asthor, and to print out:
`for(int i=0; i<numLets.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<numLets[i].length; j++){ 
                int intVal = numLets[i][j];
                System.out.print(intVal+" ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }`

Comment: @Asthor, then I got results: **8 20 0 0 \n
0 6 0 0 \n
4 10 0 0 \n
21 1 0 0**

Every time I add an array value in char[][]lets, there will be another **0** for each line. how to fix this?

Comment: @Speaky int [][] numLets = new int[lets.length][lets.length]; should be int [][] numLets = new int[lets.length][lets[0].length]; as lets.length is not the same length as the inside array in lets.

Comment: Great. Thank you @Asthor for our worthy discussion.